# Create tabbed rectangle with CSS

Tags: css, tabs

Is anybody aware of any CSS tricks that can achieve the tabbed rectangle look as shown in the image below.

Obviously this cannot be achieved using one div, however, can anybody come up with a better method than overlapping one div over another to make a gap in the border?

This is my current solution, but I feel it could be better:

HTML:

```
<div id="handle"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

CSS (Have ignored colors and positioning etc):

```css
#handle {
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
    border-right: 1px solid #666;
}

#menu {
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin-top: 19px; /* Notice it is one pixel higher then the bottom of the #handle, this covers the top border where the handle is */
}
```

**Please do not correct the above CSS if there are mistakes, I have not tested this. It is purely to show my current method of achieving this**

Any comments much appreciated

[image: Tabbed Rectangle]

**UPDATE**

This is the HTML for the menu as it stands:

```
<nav id="global-nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="homNav"><a href="#" title="Home"></a></li>
        <li id="masNav"><a href="#" title="#">#</a>
            <!-- This is where the submenu starts -->
            <div class="handle"></div>
            <div class="subMenu">
                <!-- Content Here -->
            </div>
            <!-- This is where the submenu ends -->
        </li>
        <li id="shiNav"><a href="#" title="#">#</a>
            <div class="handle"></div>
            <div class="subMenu">
                <!-- Content Here -->
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="repNav"><a href="#" title="#">#</a>
            <div class="handle"></div>
            <div class="subMenu">
                <!-- Content Here -->
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="setNav"><a href="#" title="#">#</a>
            <div class="handle"></div>
            <div class="subMenu">
                <!-- Content Here -->
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the CSS for the menu as it stands (I have not included the sub menu css yet):

```css
/* Navigation */
#global-nav {position:absolute;width:460px;height:27px;left:15px;top:43px;}

#global-nav ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
#global-nav ul li {position:relative;display:block;width:92px;height:27px;float:left;padding:0;margin-left:8px;z-index:10;cursor:pointer;background-image:url("http://beta.example.net/_images/_global/sprite.png");background-position:-173px -32px;}
#global-nav ul li:hover {background-position:-173px -59px;}
#global-nav ul li:active {background-position:-173px -86px;}
#global-nav ul li a {display:block;width:92px;height:27px;line-height:27px;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:12px;text-shadow:#666 0 -1px 0;}
#global-nav ul li:hover a {color:#666;text-shadow:#fff 0 1px 0;}
#global-nav ul li:active a {color:#666;text-shadow:none;}

/* Set styles for specific navigation buttons */
#homNav {width:47px !important;margin-left:0 !important;margin-right:12px;background-position:-126px -32px !important;}
#homNav a {width:47px !important;}
#homNav:hover {background-position:-126px -59px !important;}
#homNav:active {background-position:-126px -86px !important;}

/* Set hovers of sub menu buttons to active images */
#masNav:hover,
#shiNav:hover,
#repNav:hover,
#setNav:hover
{background-position:-173px -86px !important;}
```

Comment: It's not identical but you could borrow some ideas from http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: cmon, there are 1000s of tutorials out there for tabbed menus and you haven't even tried something?

Comment: I looked at those tabs but this is slightly more complicated as there is a border and a gap between the list item and the menu below. The height of the list item cannot be any taller than it already is

Comment: @Christoph tabbed menus are easy in most cases! However, what I am trying to achieve here is a little more complicated due to the structure of the menu. Would it help if I posted my code for the current menu?

Comment: @BenCarey of course, please do so. You could also provide a little example e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net and you will get good answers in no time. Btw. it doesn't matter if its 1px difference or 20 - it's the same way how to deal with this.

Comment: @Christoph I have updated question with my menus HTML and CSS. I have not written the CSS for the sub menus yet because I want to make sure I use the best method. The reason I have asked this question is not because I do not know how to achieve this, it is because I want to achieve it in the best way, therefore I would like other peoples opinions before I proceed to writing it myself :-)

Comment: can you make the image work? the link in the css is broken

Comment: I will upload it somewhere else as the address of this site is confidential :-) Image here: https://www.mansys.net/sprite.png

Comment: @Christoph Please dont spend too much of your time on this as I will be able to write the code myself, I just want to make sure I use the best method. Really appreciate your help so far :-)

Comment: well, i've stopped using images for such tasks. This of course depends on which browsers you will have to support and how the degradation is allowed to look like in the older browsers. But as it stands this is possible with css3 completely without images.

Comment: Yeah I know and I would love to do it using CSS3, however, as this site is more of a product/application than a standalone website, it is hugely important that it is supported by all major browsers, including the dreaded IE7+!! Is the method I suggested, where I simply overlay the `#handle` div over the top of the menu, the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a good look at this I concluded that my original method of overlaying the border was the best way to achieve this tabbed menu.

HTML:

```
<nav id="global-nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="homNav"><a href="#" title="Home"></a></li>
        <li id="masNav"><a href="#" title="#">#</a>
            <div class="subMenuHandle horizontal-sprite">
                <div class="bg-noise"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="subMenu horizontal-sprite">
                <div class="bg-noise"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="shiNav"><a href="#" title="#">#</a>
            <div class="subMenuHandle horizontal-sprite">
                <div class="bg-noise"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="subMenu horizontal-sprite">
                <div class="bg-noise"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="repNav"><a href="#" title="#">#</a>
            <div class="subMenuHandle horizontal-sprite">
                <div class="bg-noise"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="subMenu horizontal-sprite">
                <div class="bg-noise"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="setNav"><a href="#" title="#">#</a>
            <div class="subMenuHandle horizontal-sprite">
                <div class="bg-noise"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="subMenu horizontal-sprite">
                <div class="bg-noise"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (Sorry for the compression, just my way of formatting):

```css
/* Navigation */
#global-nav {position:absolute;width:460px;height:27px;left:15px;top:43px;}

#global-nav ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
#global-nav ul li {position:relative;display:block;width:92px;height:27px;float:left;padding:0;margin-left:8px;z-index:10;background-image:url("http://beta.example.net/_images/_global/sprite.png");background-position:-173px -32px;}
#global-nav ul li:hover {background-position:-173px -59px;}
#global-nav ul li:active {background-position:-173px -86px;}
#global-nav ul li a {display:block;width:92px;height:27px;line-height:27px;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:12px;text-shadow:#666 0 -1px 0;}
#global-nav ul li:hover a {color:#666;text-shadow:#fff 0 1px 0;}
#global-nav ul li:active a {color:#666;text-shadow:none;}

/* Set styles for specific navigation buttons */
#homNav {width:47px !important;margin-left:0 !important;margin-right:12px;background-position:-126px -32px !important;}
#homNav a {width:47px !important;}
#homNav:hover {background-position:-126px -59px !important;}
#homNav:active {background-position:-126px -86px !important;}

/* Set hovers of sub menu buttons to active images */
#masNav:hover,
#shiNav:hover,
#repNav:hover,
#setNav:hover
{background-position:-173px -86px !important;}

/* Set the sub menu handles */
#global-nav .subMenuHandle {position:relative;display:none;width:90px;height:12px;margin-top:-1px;border-left:1px solid #666;border-right:1px solid #666;z-index:1000;background-color:#fff;background-repeat:repeat-x;}

/* Set the sub menu container */
#global-nav .subMenu {position:relative;display:none;margin-top:-1px;width:910px;height:180px;border:1px solid #666;z-index:999;background-color:#ddd;background-position:0 -12px;background-repeat:repeat-x;}

/* Set the menu hovers to show sub menus */
#global-nav ul li:hover .subMenuHandle,
#global-nav ul li:hover .subMenu
{display:block;}

/* Set the sub menu container positions */
#masNav .subMenu {margin-left:-83px;}
#shiNav .subMenu {margin-left:-183px;}
#repNav .subMenu {margin-left:-283px;}
#setNav .subMenu {margin-left:-383px;}

/* Set the noise in the menus */
.bg-noise {position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:url("https://www.beta.net/_images/_global/bg-noise.png") repeat;}
```